# Connection of VPN with android

Tags: android, vpn

i have connected several machines with server using VPN and i have a URL which is used to connect those machine internally.Now i would like to connect with android and make operations regarding it, so how can i connect and access its related data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android has some built in VPN functionalities. You can connect to PPTP and L2TP VPN networks (you have the option in the Wireless Settings screen). However if you want to connect to a OpenVPN network you have to install a third party application called [OpenVPN Installer](https://market.android.com/search?q=openvpn&c=apps), which installs the openvpn binary, and control it by means of OpenVPN settings. The only problem is that you need a rooted phone and install the tun kernel driver by yourself (which can be complicated to find). The other way round is using Cyanogenmod, that already has builtin OpenVPN support (with all the needed stuff).

Comment: Which version of Cyanogenmod has OpenVPN support built in?